# Filtering 2 values on a field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This should be pretty simple. I want to select only products which have an empty value for `current_price` or a value of '0.00'

Here's what I have:

```
product_list = Product.objects.filter(current_price__in=['0.00', None])
```

Comment: can you explain what is the error that you get.. the Product model that you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`Q(...)`** expression as

```
from appname.models import Product
from django.db.models import Q

result = Product.objects.filter(Q(current_price=0.00) | Q(current_price=None))
```

Answer (score 0):

with the given data , see if this is what you are looking for ,

```
from appname.models import Product
result = Product.objects.filter( current_price = 0.00 or None )
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` it's complaining of the `=` in `current_price=0.00`

Comment: the  updated one works. Beware of the datatype that you filter the condition with.

Comment: The result of ***`0.00 or None`*** will ***always*** be **`None`**. So, the *`.filter( current_price = 0.00 or None )`* is ***same as*** ***`.filter( current_price = None )`***

Comment: Is it so ? I dont think so brother. Just now tested..  the resultant queryset was similar to the condition if(current_price == 0.00 OR current_price == None )